# the docker build stuck at transferring context forever

Tags: python, docker

when I using this command to build docker `Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086` image in macOS 13.2 with M1 chip, the build process blocked in transferring context forever, this is the build log output:

```
➜ docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t=reddwarf-pro/cha-server:v1.0.0 .
[+] Building 318.6s (4/10)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 671B                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10-alpine3.16                                                                      5.7s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.10-alpine3.16@sha256:b2d1f7c5ef2aad57f135104240e91c5327d9c414a58517f1080d55ed6a7a591d              312.8s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.10-alpine3.16@sha256:b2d1f7c5ef2aad57f135104240e91c5327d9c414a58517f1080d55ed6a7a591d                0.0s
 => => sha256:df0ead61b76e5f4e46838cd42d2a8c682d9ee2f368619d1b5f2dccc683f4ceaa 3.15MB / 12.29MB                                              312.8s
 => => sha256:b2d1f7c5ef2aad57f135104240e91c5327d9c414a58517f1080d55ed6a7a591d 1.65kB / 1.65kB                                                 0.0s
 => => sha256:33733c1204f5f1619290fe3a4d4bbcb28574c7df61ccf0048f46d04c29e0ad21 1.37kB / 1.37kB                                                 0.0s
 => => sha256:fb50eb7b018f767e9df8538552d47a2ddd135622357afeb6f78a2ce0515f429c 6.33kB / 6.33kB                                                 0.0s
 => => sha256:547446be3368f442c50ff95e2a2a9c85110b6b41bbb3c75b7e5ebb115f478b57 2.71MB / 2.71MB                                               227.6s
 => => sha256:fc7cc9366210bf87382129b842210a5f3b868c4400e56cfbae81b0cbaad66492 662.28kB / 662.28kB                                            51.9s
 => => sha256:1205151c85319d9ca7046006cce9419f2516d28daebd1839d5ee1eda18f21f13 240B / 240B                                                    53.3s
 => => sha256:d8f3c223bf9d2d03b40f67b94f7baa7b292e319f8c520f566cb9cbe28056a15e 3.08MB / 3.08MB                                               290.0s
 => => extracting sha256:547446be3368f442c50ff95e2a2a9c85110b6b41bbb3c75b7e5ebb115f478b57                                                      0.1s
 => => extracting sha256:fc7cc9366210bf87382129b842210a5f3b868c4400e56cfbae81b0cbaad66492                                                      0.1s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                             21.6s
 => => transferring context: 564.82MB                                                                                                         21.6s
```

what should I do to fixed this issue? this is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine3.16

LABEL jiangxiaoqiang (xiaoqiang@mail.com)

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    TZ=Asia/Shanghai

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
    && mkdir -p /root/chat-server 

# upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && apk add curl

ADD . /root/chat-server/

EXPOSE 8001

RUN pip3 install -r /root/chat-server/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /root/chat-server/
ENTRYPOINT exec python3 -m uvicorn main:app --port 8001 --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
```

Comment: What's in your context? (That's the `.` directory listed at the end of the build command.)